# How to represent types for GUI elements in XSD?

Tags: xml, user-interface, xsd

I am working with an application, where some entries need to be filled in in a GUI. Now a customer has requested a configuration file in order to bypass the GUI.
In order to get this done, I'm thinking of the following:

**Checkboxes** : use a simple integer restriction on the numbers 0 and 1:

```
<xs:simpleType name="T_Choice">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**Comboboxes** : use a union or a simple integer restriction and an empty string (in order to simulate a combobox with all values from 0 to 10, and an empty first line):

```
<xs:simpleType name="T_Combo_Choice">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But what about **radiobuttons**? In my XML file, I'm having two adjacent tags:

```
<use_old_configuration>0</use_old_configuration>
<use_new_configuration>1</use_new_configuration>
```

Now my question: how can I create a restriction in the schema in order to have the possible combinations `(0,1)` and `(1,0)`, but not `(0,0)`, `(1,1)` or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation for XSD types of your GUI components:

- **Checkboxes**: Use `xs:boolean`.
- **Comboboxes**: Use a `xs:list` restricted to length 1 of
  `xs:enumeration`.  The `xs:list` of 0 would represent no selection. 
  Name enumerations logically.
- **Radio buttons**: Assuming the traditional model where only 1 of several
  buttons must be selected, use an enumeration where where each
  enumerated value is associated with one radio button.  Name
  enumerations logically.